# How do you read a text file into a dictionary with the information on one line separated by '\t' python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

My text file reads like this:
`CSCI 160:4 CSCI 289:3  EE 201:4    MATH 208:3` (all in one line, separated by a tab `'\t'`). How do I read that text file into a dictionary with (key, val) separated at the `':'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
s = "CSCI 160:4\tCSCI 289:3\tEE 201:4\tMATH 208:3"

d = dict(item.split(":") for item in s.split("\t"))
print(d)
```

Prints:

```py
{"CSCI 160": "4", "CSCI 289": "3", "EE 201": "4", "MATH 208": "3"}
```

---

EDIT: To read from file, you can use this example (assuming your file has only one line):

```py
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    s = f_in.read().strip()

d = dict(item.split(":") for item in s.split("\t"))
print(d)
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply! Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. Got the error builtins.AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Also, would it be s = (fileName)?

Comment: @DatSoup I've updated my answer with how to read the line from the file)